# Dynamically define class with inheritance and static attributes (sqlmodel / sqlalchemy metaclasses)

Tags: python, class, dynamic, metaclass, sqlmodel

I have the following class definition that I would like to make dynamic:

```
class SQLModel_custom(SQLModel, registry=self.mapper_registry):
    metadata = MetaData(schema=self.schema)
```

I've tried something like that:

```
type('SQLModel_custom', (SQLModel, self.mapper_registry), {'metadata': MetaData(schema=self.schema)})
```

But this give me the following error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Maybe the issue comes from the fact I'm not using `registry=` when defining parent classes in the dynamic version, but I don't see how I could acheive the same result.
Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. As the error message indicates, you are calling the wrong metaclass. `SQLModel` itself is not constructed with `type`, but some other subclass of `type`. While the rules for determining the correct metaclass can be complicated, here it's simple: use the same one the (only) parent uses.
2. Only base classes are included in the 2nd argument to the metaclass; `registry` is not a base class, but a keyword argument intended to be passed to the metaclass. (If you see `self.mapper_registry` in the tuple, you should see a relevant error once you call the correct metaclass.)

The following should work:

```
mc = type(SQLModel)

SQLModel_custom = mc('SQLModel_custom', 
                     (SQLModel,),
                     {'metadata': MetaData(schema=self.schema)},
                     registry=self.mapper_registry)
```

---

Point 1 is less of an issue than I previously thought; the error message comes from trying to use the types of `SQLModel` *and* `self.mapper_registry` to determine the correct metaclass. `type` itself apparently can return an instance of the proper metaclass without you needing to call it explicitly. A simple example:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    pass


class Foo(metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass


Bar = type('Bar', (Foo,), {})


# The call to type figures out that the correct metaclass is
# type(Foo) == MyMeta, not type itself.
assert isinstance(Bar, MyMeta)
```

Comment: It seems to work well. Thank you for the explanation, but I don't really understand why I need to create the `mc` metaclass first. It seems to work equally with `type('SQLModel_custom', (SQLModel,), {'metadata': MetaData(schema=self.schema)}, registry=self.mapper_registry)`.

Comment: Hm, I guess the error could result from trying to use `type(self.mapper_registry)` to determine the metaclass. `type` itself may be able to look at the base class(es) and return an instance of the correct metaclass if you don't call the correct metaclass directly; I'm not sure.

Comment: I had misunderstood the way `type()` works. It makes much more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: `type` is weird: with one argument, it simply returns the type of its argument. With three arguments (plus any optional keyword arguments), it *creates* a new instance of `type`.